# Python: Display input as "*"

Tags: python, input

I am not very familiar with Python at all, and I am trying to do some basic tasks.
I want a user to input text, but I want it to appear as a "*". I am unsure of how to do this, and haven't come across a solution.

```
x = input("Input to appear normally: ")
y = input("I want this to appear as ******: ")
```

I have no idea what so ever on how to do this.
I will be very thankful for help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
import getpass

pswd = getpass.getpass('Password:')
```

And if you want to display input as "*", [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7838660/963881) explains how to do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I knew it would be something simple like that.
Thankyou!