# i've added a password to my python program and i need to hide it

Tags: python

I have a login and password on a python program and I wont to print a * for every letter i type in the password (im on linux by the way)

```
name = input("Name : ").lower()
password = input()("Password : ").lower()
```

Comment: And where is your question? `getpass` does exactly what you want, if it's supported by your platform/terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close.  Just to be sure, you need to `import getpass`, you then need to change

```
password = getpass.getpass()("Password : ").lower()
```

to

```
password = getpass.getpass("Password : ").lower()
```

Your parens are off.

Comment: note generally passwords are meant to be case sensitive doing a lower might not be a good ides also just for information you dont need to specify a prompt if all you want is 'Password:'

Comment: @SamLovesPython123  This is working fine for me, unless there's another requirement you didn't mention.

Comment: all i wonted is for it to replace every letter i type with a *

Comment: On many unix/linux systems, the convention is to not show anything, as replacing characters with symbols reveals how many letters your password has.  I'm not sure `getpass()` supports this, though it seems you can implement it yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838564/how-to-read-password-with-echo-in-python-console-program

Comment: i still dont get why its not changing the echoed letters to *s

Comment: If you copy-pasted the code from that other answer, please open a new question with a minimum example asking about what specifically is wrong with that code.  Otherwise it doesn't print stars because it doesn't print stars, you would have to make it.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine, the reason why your code did not work is because your parenthesis were off and therefore you were trying to call the string you got from `getpass()`.

```
import getpass 

>>> getpass.getpass("Password: ").lower()
Password:
'asdf'
```