# Python: How to "asterisk out" / hide a password whilst typing it on screen?

Tags: python, passwords, pyscripter

Auth_url isn't defined here but in the longer version it is and successfully logs in. The issue is, the input box that appears does not "asterisk out" the password. Is there a simple way to correct this issue? Thanks

```
from suds.client import Client
from suds.xsd.doctor import Import, ImportDoctor
from suds.sax.element import Element
import getpass

user = "my username"
pw = getpass.getpass("Password: ")
auth_client = Client(auth_url)
cookie = auth_client.service.authenticate(user, pw)
```

Comment: Where are you running this from ? I've tried it and it hides the input as it's supposed to do.

Comment: Pyscripter 2.7 Thanks

Comment: You could try adapting [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/510364/21945),  which implements a `getch()` function, to echo an asterisk after reading each character.

Comment: Also the answers to this question might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7838564/21945

Comment: For anyone having the same problem. This code works, the issue is with Pyscripter. If you run the code in cmd or convert it to .exe, it should work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> the issue is with Pyscripter. If you run the code in cmd or convert it to .exe, it should work correctly.